# What's the use and meaning of the [moderator-relationship] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'll put it right out there: I don't think this is a useful tag. I think its meaning is unclear and I can't imagine ever wanting or needing to use it to filter questions.

That being said, what does everyone else think? There are only four of these questions at present:

- [How to avoid being put on a pedestal by users?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/165/46)
- [How to handle moderation of users known personally?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/150/46)
- [I am being blamed for an incorrect moderator action I didn't take. What should be done?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/452/46)
- [Disciplinary action guideline for a game with chat](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/401/46)

In the first three cases I feel like I at least have a sense of why the tag is being used -- there's something about the relationship between moderators and users that seems integral to the question. But even then, the tag is frustratingly vague; does it encompass relationships between moderators? It seems like, taken purely at face value, this tag would apply to a huge portion of the questions on the site.

Is the concept that this tag wants to nail down something more to do with a moderator's *reputation among the user base*, perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

I think we should kill this tag.  For teams we already have [moderator-teams](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-teams), and *most* of the questions on this site are going to be about issues involving moderators and users.  A tag that applies to that many questions isn't meaningful.

(I was about to remove this tag from some questions when I thought to check meta for this discussion.)

Answer (score 3):

> In the first three cases I feel like I at least have a sense of why the tag is being used -- there's something about the relationship between moderators and users that seems integral to the question. But even then, the tag is frustratingly vague; does it encompass relationships between moderators?

It seems to do all of the above. It might be best to split it into [inter-mod-relationships](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inter-mod-relationships) and [mod-user-relationships](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-user-relationships). That's what I vote we do with this, if anything.

> Is the concept that this tag wants to nail down something more to do with a moderator's reputation among the user base, perhaps?

It seems that way. It is hard to really define a tag with only four questions.

I think that splitting them into [inter-mod-relationships](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inter-mod-relationships) and [mod-user-relationships](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-user-relationships) would solve this.

**EDIT:** We could also do [public-relations](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-relations). I still don't think it is easy to understand when first read, but it makes sense I guess...

Comment: Maximum tag length: 25 characters.

Comment: @FEichinger good catch. I changed "moderator" to "mod."

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin I'm going to put my opinion out there and say I don't like "mod".  That adds another [thing](http://meta.moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/64/should-tags-contain-the-word-moderator?lq=1) we would need to be aware of when tagging. Do we use mod for one tag and not another or shorten everything to mod?

Comment: @Andy I don't like it either, but I feel that there is no alternative. If you can think of one, free to add another answer since I can't think of anything. :) The only thing I can think of is *public-relations*, which is better but still not great. Still, nothing for the inter-mod relationships...

Comment: As this is a site mostly for moderators, why not just user-relationships? For inter-mod-relationships how about peer-relationships?

Comment: There is already a [tag:moderator-teams] tag; that seems fine for the mod-mod side of this.

Comment: @Styphon thats not actually the scope of the site.